# Search (filter ListView) in Fragments by writing search query in Action Bar

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Is it possible to implement search (filter ListView) in Fragments, which would filter ListView by the text, written to search query in Action Bar in the same layout immediately? Or does the search require activity class and it's impossible to deal with it?
Example: like these guys did (I'm not sure, if they used either Acitivity or Fragment)
[image]

When user adds some text to the searchbar
[image]
**EDIT: what am I doing wrong?**

```
public class AllLists extends Fragment /*implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener*/{

private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private Context context;
private int position = 0;
private String location;
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

public AllLists(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alllists, container, false);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
  //  View list_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.small_icon);
    header.setClickable(false);
   // ImageView logo = (ImageView) list_view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    position = bundle.getInt("position");
    location = bundle.getString("location");
    image.setImageDrawable(navMenuIcons.getDrawable(position));
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    items = db.getAllItems(location);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (location.equals("accommodation") || location.equals("eat") || location.equals("events")
                    || location.equals("entertainment") || location.equals("places") || location.equals("cinema")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("position", position - 1);
                i.putExtra("location", location);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}

/*SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener){

}*/

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }
        /*public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }*/
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: sure you can, just setup SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener

Comment: Is your question about how to set the listener, how to notify your fragments from the listener, or how to filter the ListViews in your fragments once they have the search string?

Comment: How can I access SearchView in Fragment, if I'm using v7 support library? The method below doesn't work:
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

Answer (score 0):

what you are aiming to do is send the search query to the fragment containing list... and to do that you need a **communication between the activity and the fragment which it contains**.. so as the user types the search query fragment containing list will filter accordingly...

**step 1** : define a public method in a fragment which will be accessed by the activity which it is attached to.

```
Class ExampleFragment {

public void refreshList(String search){
// code to refresh the list view
}
```

**step 2** : find the fragment attached to your activity by below method

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
```

**step 3** : using the fragment access the public method of that fragment and which will refresh the list view for eg:

```
 String searchQuery = "apple";
 fragment.refreshList(searchQuery)
```

}